# method does not get passed when passing the class? PHP

Tags: php, oop, yii, getter

What I want to ask is,

let's say I have a class `Info` and there's a getter in the info called `getABC()`

In a controller I assigned something like

```
$info = new Info();

$variable['info'] =$info;
```

and `$variable` is being passed into the view.

In the view, am I able to use something like `$variable['info']->getABC()` ? 
I know I can just test it out myself, and failed saying something like it did not exist and `$variable['info']` does show something though.

I just want to make sure that `$variable['info']->getABC()` is suppose to NOT work or it should but I am just doing something wrong that's why I couldn't get what's needed.

actual code below........

Class

```
class CreditCardPayment{

private $_card_type = '';
private $_card_number = '';
private $_card_number_last_4 = '';

public function setCardType($v)
{
    $this->_card_type = $v;
    return $this;
}

public function setCardNumber($v)
{
    $this->_card_number = $v;
    return $this;
}

public function setCardNumberLast4($v) {
    $lastFourDigits =  substr($v, -4);
    $output = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-' . $lastFourDigits;
    $this->_card_number_last_4 = $output;
    return $this;
}

public function getCardType() {
    return $this->_card_type;
}

public function getCardNumber() {
    return $this->_card_number;
}

public function getCardNumberLast4() {
    return $this->_card_number_last_4;
}

}
```

and in Controller let's say when it's successful....it'll be something like this where `$creditCardPayment = new CreditCardPayment` and I tried `var_dump($creditCardPayment)` that definitely info is all filled and of course those are `private` variables so I had to use the `getter` retrieve them.

Controller

```
$ordermess['creditCardPaymentInfo'] = $creditCardPayment;
 \Yii::$app->session->set('ordermess', $ordermess);
 $this->redirect('/pay/completed');
```

then in my view...I did this as testing

```
<?php 
    echo '<pre>'; 
    echo ($ordermess['creditCardPaymentInfo']->getCardNumberLast4()); 
    echo '</pre>'; 
    die; 

?>
```

then when I load the page I would get error.

> Call to a member function getCardNumberLast4() on a non-object

Comment: it sounds like a scoping issue.  If you've defined the method as Public, I would expect your code to work, ie calling $variable['info']->getABC() should return a result other than error.  BTW:  it's better to post more of your code so that others can offer better advice, like it would be valuable to see how you defined your class and methods.

Comment: @Craig alright, I will try to put more codes, it's just there are too much and I am actually digging into what is passed into me and it's using `yii framework` give me few minutes and I will try putting in some codes :D

Comment: @Craig I added some codes :D

Comment: Could you show exactly how you are creating the object and passing it into the view?

Comment: @topher creating the object I was just using `$creditCardPayment = new CreditCardPayment;` as for passing, I believe it's the `\Yii::$app->session->set('ordermess', $ordermess);` I showed above.  I tried adding parameters to the `redirect` to just pass `$creditCardPayment` but no idea why it just wouldn't pass it over and that's why I needed up have to use `$ordermess['creditCardPaymentInfo'] = $creditCardPayment;`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is supposed to work. If there is sanitization code in the function assigning variables to the view, it could be converting the object to an array.